# How do I add a dependency to an SBT build file

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I have an SBT build file like with lots of lines like this:

"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-math" % "0.5"

Specifying dependencies. I have a new Jar that I want to add to my dependencies. How do I figure out this "blah" % "blah" % "blah.0" form I should write it in?

I know this is probably a very basic question. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If the dependency you want is not available into a repository you can just put the jar a "lib" folder in the root of your project, otherwise like any dependency you should get the information (groupId, name, version and repository) of the artifact (try searching for 'maven' + library name in google).

Everything is explained in great detail in the [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html).

Answer (score 0):

for basic java libraries, a search in [MVN Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) should quickly yield the pom if are looking for. Rules about SBT resolution, particularly in Scala Crosscompiled projects, please refer to [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html)